# Angular 4 - How to get a pipe to trigger on a programmatic value change (no keyboard events)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-pipe

This is my first angualr project. I am updating an inputs value on an elements click. I would like to trigger the filtering pipe when this value is changed. The logic to trigger the pipe is in a directive. Is this possible?

**Component**

```
<input id="filter-careers" placeholder="type your title here" type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" value="">

 <div class="vacancy {{vacancy.department}}" *ngFor="let vacancy of vacancies | filter:term"
       (click)="openModalContent(vacancy.description, vacancy.positionTitle, vacancy.department, vacancy.link)">
      <p>{{vacancy.positionTitle }}</p>
  </div>
```

**Second component**

```
<div class="department" *ngFor="let department of departments" appDepartmentsDirective [departmentName]="department.name" >

      <div class="icon" [ngStyle]="{background: 'url(' + '../../assets/' + department.link + '.png' + ') center center no-repeat'}">
        <img src="../../assets/{{department.link}}.svg" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Directive**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input  } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDepartmentsDirective]'
})

export class DepartmentsDirectiveDirective {

  @Input() departmentName:string;

  constructor() { }



  @HostListener('click') click() {
    console.log('department name: ' + this.departmentName);
    if((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('filter-careers'))){
      console.log('do something here to trigger the filtering');

      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('filter-careers')).value = this.departmentName;
      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('filter-careers')).focus();

    }
    else{
      console.log('do something else');
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

By default, a pipe is only re-executed if the passed value or parameters change. If the value or parameters are objects, only different object instances are recognized as change, adding/removing values from an array or modifying properties of an object are not recognized.

If you make the pipe impure, it is executed every time change detection runs. This can cause serious performance issues.

A simple trick is to pass an additional parameters to the pipe like

```
*ngFor="let vacancy of vacancies | filter:term:dummy"
```

and every time you want the pipe to be re-executed, modify `dummy`

```
dummy:number = 0;

someHandler() {
  this.vacancies.push(someValue);
  this.dummy++;
}
```

Comment: This is good and will come in handy when i add the admin panel to add / remove vacancies... but what I'm trying to achieve now is to initiate the filter itself. When the department class element is clicked it updates the value of the #filter-careers input. when that value changes i want to initiate the filtering of the departments automatically. Any thoughts?

Comment: The question title is about pipe. I think instead of your whole `click()` method you should just do `<input (click)="term = departmentName"` (also remove `value=""`)